# Issue adding media plugin with chrome mobile app (cca), very recent

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

Up until two days ago I was installing plugins just fine with cca, until today. When I go to add the cordova media plugin as I usually do using this command in my terminal:

```
cca plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-media':Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-file
at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:268:14)
at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-file
at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:268:14)
at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I've changed nothing, it just stopped working for some reason. Any ideas as to why this is happening? I'm so confused here. I've been adding the plugin to various projects all week using this command and just today it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

Use this format instead `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media`